# Por qué el método equals no me funciona al comparar una misma matriz?

Tags: java, matriz

Lo que intento hacer es contar las palabras repetidas de una cadena, entonces leo el texto y utilizo un split() para poner cada palabra en una matriz y así pasar cada palabra al método EstáPalabra en la clase Coleccion. Cuando llego ahí lo que hago es hacer una matriz local para almacenar las palabras y saber si se repiten pero cuando utilizo el equals no me manda true ni false que es lo que quiero retornar. Asimismo utilizo herencia para pasar el tamaño de la matriz.

```
public class ContadorPalabras {
    static int val = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese un texto (Finalizar con  ENTER");
        String texto = Leer.dato();
        String[] cole = new String[texto.length()];
        cole = texto.split(" ");
        val = cole.length;
                
       Coleccion pal = new Coleccion();
       
        for (int i = 0; i < cole.length; i++) {
            if (pal.EstáPalabra(cole[i]) == true) {
                System.out.println("ENTRA");
            }else
                System.out.println("Rechaza");
        }
        
    }
    
}

   public class Coleccion extends ContadorPalabras{

      static String[] col = new String[val];
      static int[] con = new int[val];
      static int in = 0, i=0;
        

    public  boolean EstáPalabra(String pala){

      System.out.println("PALABRA: "+pala);
      boolean ele = true;
      String[] co = new String[val];
      co[in] = pala;

      for (int j = 0; j < co.length; j++) {
        if ( co[in].contains(co[j]) && in !=j ) {
         System.out.println("Se repite");
         ele = false;
        }else
         ele = true;
       }

      in=in+1;
      return ele;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

Doy por hecho que **`Leer.dato()`** trae el texto a verificar.

```
String[] cole = new String[ texto.length() ];
cole = texto.split( " " );
```

La primer linea, asigna a **cole**, un tamaño igual a la cantidad de letras que ingreso el usuario (**`texto.length()`**), la segunda, crea un `array` con un tamaño igual a la cantidad de palabras y lo llena con ellas... que es lo que necesitas, por lo tanto la primera desaparece.

```
String[] cole = texto.split( " " );
```

La clase **ContadorPalabras** quedaría así:

```
public class ContadorPalabras {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      System.out.println( "Ingrese un texto (Finalizar con  ENTER" );
      String texto = Leer.dato();
      String[] cole = texto.split( " " );

      Coleccion pal = new Coleccion();

      for( int i = 0; i < cole.length; i++ ) {
         if( pal.estaPalabra( cole[ i ] ) == true ) {
            System.out.println( "ENTRA" );
         }
         else {
            System.out.println( "Rechaza" );
         }
      }

      List <String> mapaPal = pal.getListadoPalbras();
      List <Integer> mapaCan = pal.getListadoCantidades();
      for( int i = 0; i < mapaPal.size(); i++ ) {         
         System.out.println( mapaPal.get( i ) + ":" + mapaCan.get( i ));         
      }
   }
}
```

`Herencia`: cuando una clase hereda a otra, hereda los métodos de esta, y los atributos, pero no sus valores, me explico, si tienes las clase `Padre` y la clase `Hijo`, Padre tiene un atributo `edad` que vale `48`, `Hijo` hereda a `Padre` por lo que también tiene un atributo `edad`, pero este no vale `48`, por lo que pasar valores mediante herencia no funciona.
Por otro lado, no sabes que texto va a ingresar el usuario, por lo que no tienes idea de cuantas palabras distintas vas a encontrar, si usas tu lógica, y creas un `array` de un tamaño igual a la cantidad total de palabras, te encontrarás con la desagradable sorpresa, de que al iterar sobre el, vas a encontrar valores `null`... aparte te obliga a llevar una cuenta de las palabras ingresadas para saber en que posición ingresar la siguiente... es más fácil, usar una `List`.

```
public class Coleccion extends ContadorPalabras {

   List <String> palabras = new ArrayList<>();
   List <Integer> cantidades = new ArrayList<>();

   public boolean estaPalabra( String pala ) {
      System.out.println( "PALABRA: " + pala );
      for( int j = 0; j < palabras.size(); j++ ) {
         if( palabras.get( j ).equals( pala ) ) {
            int cuantas = cantidades.get( j );
            cantidades.remove( j );
            cantidades.add( j, cuantas + 1 );
            System.out.println( "Se repite" );
            return true;
         }
      }
      palabras.add( pala );
      cantidades.add( 1 );
      return false;
   }
   
   public List <String> getListadoPalbras() {
      return palabras;
   }
   
   public List <Integer> getListadoCantidades() {
      return cantidades;
   }
}
```

Declaramos las listas `palabras` y `cantidades` fuera de **`estaPalabra`**, ya que después tenemos que retornarlas.
El método **`estaPalabra`** es super sencillo, intenta recorrer todo el `array`, si encuentra la palabra buscada, crea una variable **`cuantas`** para almacenar el valor actual de apariciones de esa palabra, va sobre la misma posición de **`cantidades`** y lo elimina, adiciona un nuevo dato en la posición del anterior, con el valor almacenado más "`1`".
Si no encontró coincidencia, sale del `for`, y agrega en palabras y en cantidades respectivamente, la palabra buscada y el numero "`1`".
Volviendo al la clase **`ContadorPalabras`**, una vez salido del `for`, traemos con los `getters` las listas e imprimimos sus respectivos valores.

PD 1: me tomé el atrevimiento de cambiar **EstáPalabra** por **estaPalabra**, el uso de acentos suele ser una fuente de errores, basta olvidarse uno... y empezar con minúscula el nombre de un método y variables, si bien la elección de un estilo es algo personal, siempre es mejor ir con la corriente.

PD 2: tranquilamente se puede prescindir de la segunda clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me gusta usar ArrayList porque siento que me es más complicado

Comment: Sobre gustos no hay nada escrito, lo importante es que te queden claro los conceptos, puedes cambiar los List por array, sin mayores problemas, solo asegurate cuando iteras, de verificar que la posición no tenga un valor null. y guardar la cantidad de palabras contenidas para saber en que posición agregas las palabras que van apareciendo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas con el código que has compartido:

1. Estás usando herencia innecesariamente. La clase `Coleccion` no
   necesita heredar de la clase `ContadorPalabras`.
2. Estás inicializando la matriz `col` y `con` con el tamaño de la variable
   `val`, pero en ese momento, `val` tiene un valor de cero. Esto significa
   que la matriz se inicializa con un tamaño de cero. Para solucionar
   esto, debes inicializar las matrices dentro del constructor de la
   clase `Coleccion`.
3. Estás usando la variable `in` para llevar un contador del número de
   palabras que se han agregado a la matriz `co`, pero no estás
   aumentando el valor de esta variable dentro del ciclo for, lo que
   significa que solo estás comparando la primera palabra que se ha
   agregado a la matriz `co`.
4. Estás usando el método `contains` para verificar si una palabra se
   repite en la matriz co, pero este método verifica si una cadena
   contiene otra cadena como subcadena, no si dos cadenas son iguales.
   Debes usar el método `equals` para comparar dos cadenas y ver si son
   iguales.

Aquí te muestro una versión corregida del código que hace lo que intentas:

```
public class ContadorPalabras {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("Ingrese un texto (Finalizar con ENTER):");
        String texto = Leer.dato();
        String[] cole = texto.split(" ");
                
        Coleccion pal = new Coleccion(cole.length);
       
        for (int i = 0; i < cole.length; i++) {
            if (pal.estaPalabra(cole[i])) {
                System.out.println("La palabra '" + cole[i] + "' ya está en la colección.");
            } else {
                pal.agregarPalabra(cole[i]);
                System.out.println("Se agregó la palabra '" + cole[i] + "' a la colección.");
            }
        }
        
    }
}

public class Coleccion {
    private String[] col;
    private int[] con;
    private int numPalabras;

    public Coleccion(int maxPalabras) {
        col = new String[maxPalabras];
        con = new int[maxPalabras];
        numPalabras = 0;
    }

    public boolean estaPalabra(String palabra) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numPalabras; i++) {
            if (col[i].equals(palabra)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void agregarPalabra(String palabra) {
        col[numPalabras] = palabra;
        con[numPalabras] = 1;
        numPalabras++;
    }
}
```

La clase `Coleccion` tiene un constructor que recibe el número máximo de palabras que se pueden almacenar en la colección. También he eliminado las variables estáticas y los contadores innecesarios. El método `estaPalabra` busca la palabra en la matriz `col` comparando cada elemento con el argumento `palabra`. El método `agregarPalabra` agrega una palabra a la matriz `col` y establece el contador para esa palabra en 1.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! No sabía lo del constructor.

Comment: Genial que te haya servido! Por favor, acepta mi respuesta marcando el check y vota positivamente :-)